# How can one know whether an ICD-10 code is a routine diagnosis code?

Tags: icd-intrntl-classif-disea

How can one know whether an ICD-10 code is a routine diagnosis code? I am asking as in the United States, some health insurances do not cover medical appointments or procedures billed with a routine diagnosis code.

Comment: How would you know what billing code they're going to use?

Comment: @CareyGregory e.g., you may ask the medical provider which ICD-10 code they use when they give an x-ray order to you.